# Research paper on machine failure prediction or predictive maintenance

Tags: data-request, research

My graduation project is about machine failure prediction or predictive maintenance. I want to know what had been done in this fields, what's similar and what is the different between these projects.

Where can I find data sets about machines failure (ex: sensors read temperature, vibration ...)

I have tried a lot to find some useful links but i can't find any link !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Predictive Maintenance Data](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/5710/predictive-maintenance-data)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at my answer [here](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/5710/predictive-maintenance-data). Basically, it goes over a primary manufacturing technology that allows collecting data from various machine tools. However, the same MTConnect "standard" can be applied to anything that can be digitally monitored using sensors. Take a look at [this](http://agent.mtconnect.org/current) "live" (but fake) XSLT stream from a 3-Axis mill.

Answer (score 2):

There was a recent article in the news about [predicting when elevators would need maintenance](http://time.com/4088793/elevator-max-cloud-thyssenkrupp/).

... but that's not released data.

If anyone had this sort of data as open data ... you might try NASA.  They make a [system for tracking aircraft maintenance](http://www.nasa.gov/agency/namis/products/MaintDetailPage.html), and I would assume that they would use it or something similar for tracking their aircraft.  (There might be something for spacecraft, but they're more likely tracked per-project, rather than in a unified system).

Comment: thank you for help .... what's the algorithms used for this?

Comment: @Menna : I have no idea for the elevator one.  I'm guessing it's likely a trade secret.  Of course, it might also just be based on having enough sensors & knowing what's out of range from normal.

Comment: no i mean for predictive maintenance for general .. thank you

Comment: I'm sure the predictive maintenance just looks at the standard deviation of the data and alerts when the values breach the upper control limit.https://www.easycalculation.com/statistics/standard-deviation.php